# Android APP: After executing AnimationListener, program got an uncaught Exception

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

My Android code is as below:

```
AnimationListener al = new Animation.AnimationListener(){

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation){
        try{
            Intent mainMenu = new Intent(Splash.this,MainMenu.class);               

            startActivity(mainMenu);
            Log.d(Splash.ACTIVITY_TAG, "Haha , this is after startActivity.");
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                String str= e.getMessage();
                Log.d(Splash.ACTIVITY_TAG, " this is in catch.");
            }
        }
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){}
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){}
    };
```

This part has no error, since it didn't catch any exception.
But it cannot go into the next activity Mainmenu. 
I debug the code through F8, and the program stop at a threat, and throw a uncaught exception.

> 06-05 22:32:31.191: E/Trace(623): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
>       06-05 22:32:31.381: W/ActivityThread(623): Application com.example.zami is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
>       06-05 22:32:31.421: I/System.out(623): Sending WAIT chunk
>       06-05 22:32:31.530: I/dalvikvm(623): Debugger is active
>       06-05 22:32:31.635: I/System.out(623): Debugger has connected
>       06-05 22:32:31.635: I/System.out(623): waiting for debugger to settle...
>       06-05 22:32:31.840: I/System.out(623): waiting for debugger to settle...
>       06-05 22:32:33.650: I/System.out(623): debugger has settled (1406)
>       06-05 22:32:34.760: D/dalvikvm(623): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 71K, 2% free 10847K/11011K, paused 45ms, total 53ms
>       06-05 22:32:34.780: I/dalvikvm-heap(623): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.873MB for 1310512-byte allocation
>       06-05 22:32:34.840: D/dalvikvm(623): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 2% free 12125K/12295K, paused 16ms+5ms, total 49ms
>       06-05 22:32:34.960: D/dalvikvm(623): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 2% free 12126K/12295K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
>       06-05 22:32:34.980: I/dalvikvm-heap(623): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.093MB for 2330784-byte allocation
>       06-05 22:32:35.040: D/dalvikvm(623): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 2% free 14402K/14599K, paused 15ms+15ms, total 61ms
>       06-05 22:32:35.630: D/gralloc_goldfish(623): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
>       06-05 22:32:38.330: D/MyAndroid(623): Haha , this is after startActivity.
>       06-05 22:33:45.141: D/AndroidRuntime(623): Shutting down VM
>       06-05 22:33:45.141: W/dalvikvm(623): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
>       06-05 22:33:47.050: E/AndroidRuntime(623): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       06-05 22:33:47.050: E/AndroidRuntime(623): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity   {com.example.zami/com.example.zami.Splash} did not call through to super.onPause()
>       06-05 22:33:47.050: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5110)
>       06-05 22:33:47.050: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1225)
>       06-05 22:33:47.050: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2825)
>       06-05 22:33:47.050: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2794)
>       06-05 22:33:47.050: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2772)
>       06-05 22:33:47.050: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:130)
>       06-05 22:33:47.050: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
>       06-05 22:33:47.050: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       06-05 22:33:47.050: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>       06-05 22:33:47.050: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>       06-05 22:33:47.050: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       06-05 22:33:47.050: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>       06-05 22:33:47.050: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>       06-05 22:33:47.050: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>       06-05 22:33:47.050: E/AndroidRuntime(623):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Can you post the LogCat output of this exception? Without it we'll be shooting in the dark ...

Comment: How you are saying no exception ?

Comment: Do  `e.printStackTrace()` to get the Exception in LogCat and post the exception here.

Comment: Is there the MainMenu activity in your manifest?

Comment: I have attached LogCat, but I don't see exception.

Comment: @Massimo, yes, there is MainMenu in manifest.

Comment: Why are you setting the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK? If you want the new activity to be the first one of the stack just finish the current activity (that flag is useful especially when you start a new activity from a notification). Furthermore, if you really need it, it is a static field of the class Intent.

Comment: Probably the exception is on the activity MainMenu but you cannot catch it because you started the activity with the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: @Massimo，yes you are right, i don't need FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

Comment: @Massimo,when I remove FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, I got error ad above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your problem description in logs:

> android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity
>   {com.example.zami/com.example.zami.Splash} did not call through to
>   super.onPause()

So, find your onPause method in Splash activity and call super.onPause() there.

**UPDATE**

You should call super methods in each lifecycle callback if you want to override it in derived class.